# Is this a fixed expression: der Sache näher kommen?

Tags: phrase

When I found these in DWDS, I was perplexed by "der Sache" being in dative declension. Is this a fixed phrase like,

> der Sache auf den Grund gehen/kommen

> 1: "Vampire Diaries" Man on Fire, 2014 (Filmuntertitel)
> Jetzt kommen wir **der Sache** schon näher.

> 2: "Grimm" Nobody Knows the Trubel I've Seen, 2014 (Filmuntertitel)
> Wir kommen **der Sache** näher.

> 5: "White Collar" The Original, 2013 (Filmuntertitel)
> Ja, wir kommen **der Sache** näher. -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is, of course a fixed expression, but fixed expressions still have to follow grammar rules.

You could also simply argue that the verb "näherkommen" is a compound verb that takes a dative object (see your dictionary of choice), which would be a perfect (and most pragmatic, but correct) answer, but still doesn't *explain* the dative.

It is actually very difficult to really explain what the dative does in a language that doesn't know this case. One of the many purposes of the dative is that it *can change the viewpoint* from the subject to the object (just as the dative in its most literal form ["give"] somewhat changes the viewpoint from the actor to the receiver).
Compare the following sentences:

> Ich gehe auf das Gebäude zu

uses accusative, because I am moving, and from my viewpoint, I am moving towards the building while

> Ich nähere mich dem Gebäude

still sees me moving, but in this example the origin of measurement (or, the viewpoint) is *from* the object that experiences me closing in.

This also works with non-spatial distances like in

> Der Schwamm ist mir zu nass

(The sponge is too wet [for my taste]). Here, the origin of measurement of that non-spatial distance - between being unacceptably-wet and acceptably-wet - is *me* (the object) and the [for my taste] part (i.e. the viewpoint) is completely expressed by the dative.

Comment: I am inspired to investigate the dative case with renewed enthusiasm. Thank you for your stimulating insights.

Answer (score 3):

It is a fixed phrase to be sure: *der Sache näherkommen* = to get a clearer idea of the issue at hand. The underlying idea is that when investigating a matter, you are at first “remote” from the core problem, and you hope to get closer to it and finally find it.

But the dative follows easily from the fact that *nah* regularly stands with the dative (*den Tränen nah* = “close to tears”). Because of that *näherkommen* (= to approach) also regularly has a dative object (e.g. *Kommen Sie mir nicht näher*, “Do not come closer to me.”).

Comment: Is it not non-separated "näherkommen"?

Comment: @OranMatheus According to Duden, yes; I was seduced by the spelling used in the question. That does not affect the grammatical issue discussed here, though.

Comment: There are actually two parts to the question: Is it a fixed phrase and why the dative? You don't need a fixed phrase to have a dative that sounds odd to an English speaker, There just happens to be both in this case.